# Request for tag creation

Tags: feature-request, tagging

I'm asking if someone could consider the creation of the tag `vacuum`. It is an Postgresql operation and I think it would be well employed in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/disk-file-effects-of-delete-and-vacuum)

Comment: I should've answered with "so considered, contemplated, contracted, contempted, completed"

Comment: Reminds me of Yul Brenner as Pharaoh saying "So shall it be written. So shall it be done." :)

Answer (score 2):

So done.